# Given the distance measure for two points and the point $p = (0,2)$, which of the following points have the same distance as $p$ from the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, symmetric-matrices, change-of-basis

Given the distance measure dist:
$$\mathrm{dist}(x,y)  =
\sqrt{(x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2)\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0\\ 
0 & 4 
\end{pmatrix} (x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2)^{T} } $$

for two dimensional points and the point $p=(0,2)$, which of the following points have the same distance as $p$ from the origin $(0,0)$?

- $(4,0)$
- $\color{red}{(2,0)}$
- $(2,1)$
- $(\sqrt{6},0)$
- $(\sqrt{7},0)$
- $\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{16}{3}},0 \right)$
- $\color{red}{(0,-2)}$

---

The answers in red are my solutions, which I found through [this work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK8se.jpg). However the correct solutions from the Prof. are $(2,1)$ , $\left(\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}}, 0\right)$, and $(0,-2)$.

I just want to know why answers $(2,1)$ and $\left(\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}}, 0\right)$ are correct, it makes no sense to me?

Comment: A MathJax tutorial for typesetting math here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two points $x = (x_1,x_2)$ and $y =(y_1,y_2)$ we have,

$$\begin{split}
\mathrm{dist}(x,y)  =&
\sqrt{(x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2)\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0\\ 
0 & 4 
\end{pmatrix} (x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2)^{T} } \\
=& \sqrt{(x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2)\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0\\ 
0 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
x_1-y_1 \\
x_2-y_2  
\end{pmatrix}  } \\
=& \sqrt{(x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2) \begin{pmatrix}
3(x_1-y_1) \\
4(x_2-y_2)  
\end{pmatrix}  }\\
=& \sqrt{3(x_1-y_1)^2+4(x_2-y_2)^2}
\end{split}$$

Therefore if $y = (0,0)$ then,

$$\mathrm{dist}(x,(0,0)) = \sqrt{3x_1^2+4x_2^2}$$

Hence,

$$\boxed{\mathrm{dist}(p,(0,0)) =\sqrt{3\cdot0^2+4\cdot 2^2}=4}$$

$$\mathrm{dist}((4,0),(0,0)) =\sqrt{3\cdot4^2+4\cdot 0^2}=4\sqrt{3}$$

$$\mathrm{dist}((2,0),(0,0)) =\sqrt{3\cdot2^2+4\cdot 0^2}=2\sqrt{3}$$

$$\boxed{\mathrm{dist}((2,1),(0,0)) =\sqrt{3\cdot2^2+4\cdot 1^2}=4}$$

$$\mathrm{dist}((\sqrt{6},0),(0,0)) =\sqrt{3\cdot\sqrt{6}^2+4\cdot 0^2}=3\sqrt{2}$$

$$\mathrm{dist}((\sqrt{7},0),(0,0)) =\sqrt{3\cdot\sqrt{7}^2+4\cdot 0^2}=\sqrt{21}$$

$$\boxed{\mathrm{dist}\left(\left(\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}},0\right),(0,0)\right) =\sqrt{16+4\cdot 0^2}=4}$$

$$\boxed{\mathrm{dist}((0,-2),(0,0)) =\sqrt{3\cdot0^2+4\cdot (-2)^2}=4}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution / However I attached a picture how I solved in my way if you could told me what was the mistake I done

Comment: @HassanElsayed You are welcome, I am glad I could help. If you have any question please let me know. And feel free to accept this answer if you found it useful.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK8se.jpg

Comment: I hope the link for the image is working Axel

Comment: @HassanElsayed The mistake you made is because you were mistaken by the notations. $x = (x_1,x_2)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2)$, **not** $x = (x_1,y_1)$...

Comment: @HassanElsayed That's right, the notations could be misleading. But if you switch them then it is not a distance anymore.

Comment: oh yes that is it , I was so confused about that, because I learned in the school that any point should have an x and y value especially when we want to draw for example a linear graph , Thank you very much Axel, It really help alot

Comment: @HassanElsayed I agree, the exercise lacked a bit of clarity on the notations. You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if you want, I would appreciate it (but it is up to you :-) ).